# selector in react-testing-library that can retrieve a number of matches by getAllByText

Tags: react-testing-library

At the moment I am doing this to pull back all the rows of a table:

```
const { getByTestId } = renderWithRouter(businessWithContext);

const firstTableRow = await waitForElement(() => getByTestId("row-1-name"));
const secondTableRow = await waitForElement(() => getByTestId("row-2-name"));

expect(firstTableRow.textContent).toBe("test1");
expect(secondTableRow.textContent).toBe("test2");
```

I would rather do something like this:

```
const rows = await waitForElement(() => getAllByText(/^row-*/gi));
```

But I get this error:

> Unable to find an element with the text: /^row-*/gi. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `getAllByText` but you really want to query by `data-testid`. This will work:

```
getAllByTestId(/^row-*/)
```